# Highcharts with custom scaling in upper regions

Tags: javascript, highcharts, boxplot

I would like to know how to achieve a custom scale for a chart in Highcharts. I want to display a boxplot which has very high whiskers. The normal values to display are between 500 and 1000 but there are some anomalies which are about 6000 on y-axis. This is causing the whole chart to be squeezed and the scaling is so small that you can't determine the boxplots correctly. I would like to increase the tick-size between 1000 and 6000 to decrease the heigt of the chart.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Highcharts provides **breaks** functionality that seems to be ideal for your case: https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/yAxis.breaks

Another approach is to change the yAxis type to **logarithmic**: https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/yAxis.type

### **EDIT**

The discussion in the comments section reveals that the OP needs rather custom y axis formatting than `breaks` functionality.

**Here's how to approach this issue:**

The problem here is that axes in Highcharts can only have either constant or logarythmic scales. Your example shows irregular scale - the values are not in constant or logarythmic order ([0, 3, 10, 30, 150]).

Here's what I've done to mimic that kind of look and behaviour:

I set `tickPositions` to `[0, 1, 2, 3, 4]` - these are the actual values that appear on the chart. As you can see the distance between all these numbers is constant: `1`.

Then I used `formatter` to display corresponding number from `ranges` array for each label.

```
  yAxis: {
    tickPositions: [0, 1, 2, 3, 4],
    labels: {
      formatter: function() {
        return ranges[this.pos];
      }
    }
  },
```

Before I passed the data to the chart constructor I converted all the values so that they're between 0 and 4:

```
  series: [{
    data: [2, 120].map(function(val) {

      var range = findRange(val);

      var y = range.index + (val - range.low) / (range.high - range.low);

      return {
        y: y,
        originalValue: val
      };
    })
  }]
```

Finally I used `originalValue` property in `tooltip.format` string to print to the user the number before the conversion.

```
  tooltip: {
    pointFormat: "<span style='color:{point.color}'>\u25CF</span> {series.name}: <b>{point.originalValue}</b><br/>"
  },
```

This example is simplified to the line series case but can be easily adjusted to boxplot series. The code serves only for the example purposes and should be improved - it's easy to cause an error within it.

**Live working demo:** https://jsfiddle.net/kkulig/ytjz1jej/

**API references:**

- https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/tooltip.pointFormat
- https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/yAxis.tickPositions
- https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/xAxis.labels.formatter

Comment: Thank you for your answer. "Breaks" is exactly what i was searching for but unfortunately it does not show any effect on my Boxplot chart :-/

Comment: Have you imported **broken axis** module (`<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/modules/broken-axis.js"></script>`)?

Comment: Thank you! I made the breaks work but now the problem is that I somehow have a scaling like 4 sections on yAxis which have a different interval like: 1. from 0 to 3 seconds - 2. from 3 to 10 seconds and 3. from 10 to 30 seconds and 4. from 30 to 150 seconds. Each of them has to be the same size. Breaks on the yAxis are causing trouble for those anomalies because they will not show up...

Comment: ![Sketch](https://i.imgur.com/KxGFJHz.png).  I attached an image which is hopefully helpling to explain.

Comment: Do you want the distances between points in these ranges to be constant? e.g. 90 is exactly between 30 and 150, 20 is exactly between 10 and 30 etc.

Comment: Yes it would be the best if those distances would be constant. I plan to have the boxplot to show in full height and then a scatter series which is placed on top of the whisker.   BTW: The alghorithmic solution is not matching what i need to accomplish :-/

Comment: Did you find out a way to archieve this?

Comment: I made it work with Boxplots besides the fact that when i call the function `highcharts().series[0].setData({y: newData, originalValue: originalData}` the box plot does not know that it has to use the array of Points in "newData". Can you tell me how to achieve that the Boxplot is using the first object and just use the second one for the tooltip?

Comment: Refer to this **API page**: https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/series.boxplot.data As you can see data for a series must be an array of points (in the comment above you used an object for this which is not correct). Every point can be either represented by an array of 6 values (e.g. `[1, 22, 44, 55, 13, 11]`) or an object (e.g. `{low: 4, high: 5, ...}`). In this case I recommend using the second form like this: `{low: 4, originalLow: 150, high: 5, originalHigh: 220, etc...}`